# Group data based on multiple keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Received JSON response

```js
[{
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "abc"
  },
  {
    "name": "B1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "pqr"
  },
  {
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-14",
    "comment": "mno"
  }
]
```

Expected output

```
[
  {
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "A1",
        "date": "2019-03-13",
        "comment": "xyz"
      },
      {
        "name": "A1",
        "date": "2019-03-13",
        "comment": "abc"
      }
    ],
    {
      "name": "A1",
      "date": "2019-03-14",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "A1",
          "date": "2019-03-14",
          "comment": "mno"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "date": "2019-03-13",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "B1",
          "date": "2019-03-13",
          "comment": "pqr"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I want to create new javascript array which contains unique name & date and its respective data.

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Why the duplication of data?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array#reduce` to group date based on the `name` & `date` in an object accumulator, then extract all values using `Object.values()`.

```js
let data = [{ "name": "A1", "date": "2019-03-13", "comment": "xyz" }, { "name": "A1", "date": "2019-03-13", "comment": "abc" }, { "name": "B1", "date": "2019-03-13", "comment": "pqr" }, { "name": "A1", "date": "2019-03-14", "comment": "mno" } ],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,{name,date, comment}) => {
      r[name + "_" + date] = r[name + "_" + date] || {name, date, data: []};
      r[name + "_" + date].data.push({name,date,comment});
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I took more time to post this question compare to your so quick response. Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 3):

You could take an array for the wanted grouping and look for the object.

```js
var data = [{ name: "A1", date: "2019-03-13", comment: "xyz" }, { name: "A1", date: "2019-03-13", comment: "abc" }, { name: "B1", date: "2019-03-13", comment: "pqr" }, { name: "A1", date: "2019-03-14", comment: "mno" }],
    groupBy = ['name', 'date'],
    grouped = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var temp = r.find(p => groupBy.every(k => o[k] === p[k]));
        if (!temp) {
            r.push(temp = Object.assign(...groupBy.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })), { data: [] }));
        }
        temp.data.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to collect the values:

```js
var input = [{
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "abc"
  },
  {
    "name": "B1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "pqr"
  },
  {
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-14",
    "comment": "mno"
  }
]

var res = input.reduce((acc, {name, date, comment}) => {
    var found = acc.find(el => el.name === name && el.date === date);
    return found 
        ? found.data.push({name, date, comment}) && acc 
        : [...acc, {name, date, data: [{name, date, comment}]}];
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

an **Easy** way to do that :

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "abc"
  },
   {
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "fffffffff"
  },
  {
    "name": "B1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "pqr"
  },
   {
    "name": "B1",
    "date": "2019-03-13",
    "comment": "hhhhhhhhhhh"
  },
  {
    "name": "A1",
    "date": "2019-03-14",
    "comment": "mno"
  }
]


const res = data.reduce((all, acc) => {

  const found = all.find(o => o.name === acc.name && o.date === acc.date)

  if (found === undefined) {
    all.push(acc)
  } else {
    found.data = (found.data || []).concat(acc)
  }

  return all;

}, [])

console.log(res)
```